# How to prevent SearchView from auto-clearing the searched text

Tags: android, android-actionbar, searchview

### Normal Behavior:

- When I request search in the `SearchView` widget on `ActionBar`, after
  clicking soft-keyboard's search  action button, the input text is
  cleared from the `SearchView`.

### My desired behavior:

- I want the my **input text to remain** the same, when I perform search. How is that possible?

---

I have read official docs for [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html), and guides from [here](http://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html), and also [here](http://developer.android.com/training/search/index.html), but haven't had any luck.

EDIT:
I discovered that this text reset happens whenever I scroll my ViewPager.

Comment: Normally the text will not be cleared unless you do so.

Comment: Does your widget call another activity to handle the query?

Comment: @user3249477 No My "sngle-top" activity handles the intent itself.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
  mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query)
        {
            mSearchView.setQuery(query,false);
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText)
        {
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Worked for me. I'm using appcompat.v7.SearchView and on submit I collapse the menu item. Whenever I perform a new search, the text will be cleared and the adapter filter will also be. I strongly recommend the use of AppCompat SearchView

Answer (score 0):

If your search widget calls another activity to handle the query, it gets cleared because the activity is newly created.

Therefore you need to set the query manually from 2 places:

- `onCreateOptionsMenu` where you initialize your search widget
- `onNewIntent` where you receive your query

Why from 2 places? Because if the search-handling activity is newly created, `onNewIntent` is called first and the search widget is not yet ready to be used. In that case save the query at `onNewIntent` and set it at `onCreateOptionsMenu`. Otherwise it can be directly set at `onNewIntent`.

Here's an example:

```
private String mQuery;
private SearchView mSearchView;

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    mQuery = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
    if (mSearchView != null) {
        mSearchView.setQuery(mQuery, false);
    }
    // Do something with the new query
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the actionbar items
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.actionbar_items, menu);

    // Get SearchView and set the searchable configuration
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search).getActionView();
    mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    // Disable collapsing the search widget
    mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
    // Set the query
    mSearchView.setQuery(mQuery, false);

    return true;
}
```